# Importing multiple matrices or multidimensional arrays from a text file

Tags: matrix, import

I have a code written in Fortran which outputs a large block-diagonal matrix, which is then written into a file in blocks. I want to know how best to import these matrices into Mathematica (I don't necessarily need to reconstruct the full block-diagonal matrix). The `Import` function seems to be very unhelpful when it comes to importing .dat files. Using `Import["filename.dat","Table"]` places a comma every time there is a space, enclosing each line in brackets. This is fine for a single matrix, but I have multiple matrices all in the same file separated by blank spaces. For example if I had a file

```
a b 
c d

A B
C D
```

After importing I get

```
{{a,b},{c,d},{},{A,B},{C,D}}
```

I can write a routine to break these apart using the `{}` as a separator but there must be some simpler way of doing this. Note that with Fortran it is very hard to control the number of spaces, so I cannot write complex expressions like `{i,j}->a` because generally each number is printed with a fixed number of digits, leaving extra white spaces which Mathematica will convert into extra commas.

Comment: *Note that with Fortran it is very hard to control the number of spaces* It really isn't, and maybe your effort would be better directed at modifying the code to write Mathematica-friendly files.  Which would be a question for another site.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction before I do so? I am only familiar with using the basic fortran formatted output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split it like this

```
dataIn={{a,b},{c,d},{},{A0,B0},{C0,D0}};
newData=SplitBy[dataIn,#=={}&]
newData=DeleteCases[newData,{{}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This worked perfectly, I knew it must be possible but couldn't figure out how to do it

Comment: The documentation for `SplitBy` does not make very it clear how to separate a list this way, which I would think would be an obvious application